# How did Nunnally and Sayoko survive the FLEIJA?

Tags: code-geass

The sheer action of the FLEIJA leaves behind a very neat crater and turns matter in its radius into a vacuum (airborne units tend to get blown into the blast center). How did Nunnally and Sayoko survive that?

Comment: Are you referring to the last usage of FLEIJA (during the final episodes of Code Geass R2? If not, what exact event are you referring to?

Comment: The one Suzaku fired aboard his mecha, destroying the Governors residence and the built-up settlement.

Comment: compare http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotQuiteDead

Comment: @aitchnyu, was that the episode when Lelouch used his geass on Suzaku to command him to live? I just need to confirm.

Comment: @xjshiya no. its a tad later. some 2 or 3 episodes before S1 final

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This blogpost](http://animehistory.wordpress.com/2008/09/05/theory-of-a-live-girl-code-geass-spoilers-inside/) adequately explains how she could have survived.
I also do not believe there was as much of a vacuum because at that point in time the FLEIJAs still had a limiter. It was not until the destruction of the Capital city of Pendragon that the limiters were removed.

This is the summary of the link:

> After Sayoko rescued Kallen she went on ahead to find Nunnally and to try and Rendevouz with Rolo and found the ship Nunally was on. Around the same time the Gefjun disturbers were disabled and Nunnally’s ship left with Sayoko and her men aboard.  She never passed Rolo because he hadn’t even reached the hangar yet.
>
> Eight minutes later Rohmeyer is on a decoy ship with KF’s to make it look like the governor general is aboard and Rolo walks in to find the ship, assuming reasonably that Nunally is on it he commandeers a KF to try and blow up the ship and kill her.  Meanwhile Sayoko barges in on Nunnally in the ship she’s really on and Rohmeyer doesn’t respond at all because she’s actually on the decoy back in the hangar.  Nunnally’s ship is probably just outside the area by this point.  When the bomb goes off Rohmeyer is caught in it in her decoy ship and goes up in a ball of flames.  Rolo has run away once he thinks he knows what’s going on with Fleija (whatever it’s called) and somehow made it to safety.
>
> How? I’m not sure as that thing had a pretty big blast radius.  So when he reports to Rolo he talks about the ship Rohmeyer is on and really isn’t lying when he says Nunnally is dead, because he honestly thinks she is.  In reality I think she’s okay and with Sayoko elsewhere.  Though that elsewhere might be in Schneizel’s clutches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the FLEIJA that was used by Suzaku was not as powerful as the ones used by Prince Shnizle because Shnizle removed the limiter. Now if I can remember correctly Nunnally and Sayoko were underground and just out of the blast radius. Now how Nunnally, Sayoko and Gilford disappeared is uncertain. Without the power I believe that the outer blast radius is just a light show, and pulls then pushes out. I believe it threw them in some random direction out of sight. Stupid I know, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up from Code Geass (or any related materials) itself?

Comment: Remember the scene where Suzaku laughs like a maniac in the middle of the massive blast crater? One that resulted from irrecoverable loss of matter within it? How do you imply its not powerful enough?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything to back this up from Code Geass (or any related materials) itself? –  Maroon 2 days ago

As a matter of fact I do. In Season 2 Episode 23 Floyd, Miss Cecile, and Nina talk about the FLEIJA that destroyed the Capital Pendragon, and Miss Cecile points out that the FLEIJA that Shnizal used that destroyed the Capital Pendragon was more 10x the destruction range than the one Suzaku use. Nina realized that he removed both the effect range and detination time limiter. These FLEIJA's Shnizle uses go critical when they are fired as he mentions when Lelouch orders his men to charge at the FLEIJA's. Now the FLEIJA's do pull things into the center of the blast because in the battle of Lelouch and Shnizal, Shnizal fired a FLEIJA and everything was pulled into the center. You may say that it was Lelouches order to charge at the FLEIJA and he did but if you see the environment like the oceans this shows things get pulled into the center of the blast. I believe FLEIJA's do not explode, but implode.

If you want to watch the final episodes of Code Geass Lelouch of the Rebelion R2 go to animefreak.tv and watch Episodes 23-25

P.S this does not explain everything about the FLEIJA's but it gave me enough to reach my conclusions

Comment: If you're Lorenzo (from the earlier post) and you were trying to add information to it, you should edit it in instead of making a new post.

Comment: I believe that stuff is pulled in because of air rushing to fill in a vacuum. [link](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1299/why-does-an-atom-bomb-form-a-mushroom-cloud). And it does not answer the question: the explosion event was big enough to apparently consume Nunnaly and a massive amount of matter and remove it without a trace.

Comment: [A user](http://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31774) tried to add this: "The Fleija not only implodes but destroyed everything in the radius. The first stage is an explosion that destroys all of the matter and replaces it with a vacuum. The second stage happens when all of the air surrounding that area rushes into the vacuum pulling everything with it. It is seen very clearly that the entirely of the governors building including the underground area and most of area 11 was caught in the blast including the area Nunnelley was in. by all rights she should've been disintegrated."